# PostgreSQL Index Optimization

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

currently I have the following indeces for the below SQL Select statement. Nevertheless the query seems still slow to me (10.000 records). Do you have any recommendations?

1. index category_id
2. index delivery_date
3. index on product_id, product_name

Here's my DDL:

```
Create table product (    
  product_id serial,
  category_id int2,
  product_name varchar(50),
  delivery_date timestamp,
  subtitle varchar(20),
  price numeric(10,2),
  retail_price numeric(10,2),
  language_id int2,
  store_id int2,
  reseller_id int2    
);
```

and SQL:

```
Select * 
from product 
WHERE delivery_date > '2012-10-20 06:00:00' AND category_id = 1 
ORDER BY product_id, product_name;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Below the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Sort  (cost=18.11..18.12 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=0 loops=1)
Sort Key: product_id, product_name
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  Seq Scan on product  (cost=0.00..18.10 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
Filter: ((delivery_date > '2012-10-20 06:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (category_id = 1))
Total runtime: 0.098 ms
```

Comment: Edit your question, and paste the output of `explain analyze <your select statement>`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info - please show Pg version, `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` output, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely ideal configuration for your query would be to have compound index for `(delivery_date, category_id, product_id)` or `(category_id, delivery_date, product_id)`.

In practice, having index for just `(category_id, product_id)` may be enough to get acceptable performance.

At any rate, `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <original_query>` is your best friend.

One more note: in your query, `ORDER BY product_id, product_name` is always going to get the same result as simply `ORDER BY product_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if I don't need the product_name for sorting in the query, why don't we need to add the product_name to the compound index?

Comment: Exactly because of that. If, for whatever reason, you decided to not use product_id in your query (in ORDER BY or in WHERE clause), but used product_name, then you should have added compound index with product_name in it

Comment: So generally spoken the compound index should contain all the cols of the "where" and "sort" clause?

Comment: If you have such index it will be good. There are some other situations when indexing is helpful, like DISTINCT, GROUP BY. But, adding all possible compound indexes is wasteful. In general, index is only helpful if it has very high selectivity (less than 1 in 100 or more). That's why you should always EXPLAIN ANALYZE first